# Clicking a button and reading an element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to click a link on a page and read a certain element once the button is clicked but keep encountering this error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="clink-hold">...</li> is not clickable at point (367, 727). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/21732118914/box_live-medrectangle-2_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/21732118914/box_live-medrectangle-2_0" width="970" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="13" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

This is the code I have written

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
page_link = 'https://box.live/fight-results/'
chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver'
def click_info():
    cdriver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    cdriver.get(page_link)
    cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('clink-hold').click()
    sleep(10)
    text=cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('name').text
    print(text)
click_info()
```

Comment: Seems to need switch to iframe

Comment: @Wonka what do you mean?

Comment: Seems that element that you are targeting is inside `iframe` so you need to switch to  `iframe` first.
`driver.switch_to.frame('your frame')'

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is Google ads that overlaps your button:

[image]

You need to first close the ads. Here is the cross [x] element:

`<span class="ezmob-footer-close" onclick="document.getElementById('ezmobfooter').style.display='none';">x</span>`

And then proceed with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers already added. I managed to resolve this issue. I realized that as Alexey mentioned, there is an element (ad) covering what i am trying to click. 
This is what I did to resolve this

```
def click_info():
    cdriver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    cdriver.get(page_link)
    element = cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('clink-hold')
    cdriver = cdriver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',element)
    text=cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('contestant-name line-ignore').text
    print(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch to iframe :

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='ifram_class_name']")
```

and then :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('clink-hold').click()
sleep(10)
text=cdriver.find_element_by_class_name('name').text
print(text)
```

finally:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```